# How to navigate in root and close application when I used shortcut back button phone

Tags: nativescript, router, back, angular2-nativescript

I have this routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'fp', component: FirstPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'images', component: ImageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'image/:id', component: ImageComponentgetbyId
      },
      {
        path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFirstComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home/fp', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

I navigate, in fp, images, image/1, images, image/2, images, image/3, images, settings,fp.

When I click shortcut back button phone I navigate step by step in all route, fp,  settings, images, image/3, images, image/2, images, image/1,image,fp, close applicatin.

When I click shortcut back button phone I want to navigate in root and close applications. If I am in image/1 I want to navigate in image and close applications.

Please can you ask me any idea how to implement this?

Comment: You can simply use `router-outlet` instead of `page-router-outlet` and this way the hardware back button will skip all router-outlet navigation and directly go back to the route in page-route-outlet (or exit the app)

Comment: In HomeComponent I use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and in AppComponent I use `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>` in module.ts `@NgModule({ bootstrap: [ AppComponent],` When I clcik back, this navigate in  path login and show this error: `System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SecuritySystemMobile/files/app/services/events.service.js', line: 33, column: 46`

Comment: @NickIliev any idea please?